# Transavia and Vueling lugages rules

Tags: legal, hand-luggage, amsterdam, transavia, vueling

I am going to Amsterdam to do a job interview, the company bought for me the two tickets to go and come back.

I will be using two flights companies, which are Transavia and Vueling.

in the boarding pass, I see this:

[image]

and this;

[image]

so I need to know what king of luggage can I have with me.

Is it just the 10 (more or less like a laptop bag) or I can take the standard luggage which is **according to my experience with Easyjet and Ryanair** 56 x 45 x 25 cm ?

Comment: In my experience, Vueling is quite flexible on hand luggage. You can normally carry a couple of bags without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Transavia](https://www.transavia.com/en-EU/service/hand-luggage/) website and [Vueling](http://www.vueling.com/en/vueling-services/prepare-your-trip/luggage) you're allowed to take 45x40x25 and 40x20x55 accordingly. Both sites say 10 kg max. Make sure it is only one piece, so no purse, no laptop bags, etc. allowed (put them inside the biggest one).

I have Samsonite small bag that sold with "cabin size" label ([something like this](http://www.samsonite.co.uk/smarttop-upright-50cm/75135.html?dwvar_75135_color=1549&cgid=SAMS080#start=11)), and I never had any problems to get on board.

Comment: I edited the links to be inline so that the post looks better. Check this feature out (highlight the words then click ctrl+L to open the link editing popup).

Comment: I also have laptop backpack which is big enough for box with toothbrush and two changes of clothes. Also never had issue with it